# Error 500 protecting a single url with .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I tried to implement this code into my .htaccess on wordpress.

Everything works fine but when you get access, it throws an 500 Error and redirects me to my hosting park website. It seems that it doesn't load the content. Not sure if the problem is that the path I'm providing doesn't contain the actual content.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/quetecalles require_auth=true

AuthUserFile /kaycho.com/wp-admin/.htpasswrd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

The snippet is based on this article
[Error 500 protecting a single url with .htpasswd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710356/error-500-protecting-a-single-url-with-htpasswd?noredirect=1#comment125004073_70710356)

Comment: Please format the code. As it's currently "formatted" it is indeed invalid - but is that just a badly formatted question or how your actual code is formatted?

Comment: thank you, just started here and I didn't know how to format my code properly. My main issue with the code is that instead of redirecting me to the actual content of the page, it takes me to a blank server page from my host provider. Looking at the console, it throw an 500 error regarding that it doesn't find the content of the URL i'm requesting.

Comment: A 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is usually no way to accurately answer a question like this without seeing the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> AuthUserFile /kaycho.com/wp-admin/.htpasswrd
> ```

The file-path to your password file looks incorrect. This needs to be an absolute filesystem-path, not a root relative URL-path (which is what this looks like). If the path is incorrect and the password file cannot be found then you'll get a 500 Internal Server Error response when submitting the username/password.

Ideally, this should be a file-path outside of your document root directory - that is naturally inaccessible to user requests. It should not be in the same location as the `.htaccess` file implementing the protection.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right! the root file was completely wrong! Thank you so much!